# Switch icon in ionic2 after click

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have list of item, each of items has button with `ion-icon`

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="{{item.logo}}" />
          </ion-avatar>

          <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>

            <button clear (click)="changeIcon(shop)" item-right>
                    <ion-icon name="ios-heart-outline" ></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

and I want to change this icon to `ios-heart` after click on button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you can see in [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#icons) you can set the icon using a variable like this:

In your view:

```
<ion-icon [name]="myIcon"></ion-icon>
```

And then in your code:

```
export class MyFirstPage {
  // use the home icon
  myIcon: string = "home";
}
```

So in your case, I'd add the icon name to each element in the array

```
public items: [] = [
  {
    "logo" : "...",
    "name" : "...",
    "iconName" : "ios-heart-outline"
  },
  //...
];
```

Then in your view, I 'd change this part of the code:

```
<button clear (click)="changeIcon(item)" item-right>
  <ion-icon [name]="item.iconName" ></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Please notice that now in the `changeIcon()` method we receive the `item` so all we have to do is changing the name of the icon like this:

```
public changeIcon(theItem): void {
    theItem.iconName = "ios-heart";
}
```