# Ionic 2 - Switch icon [name] on click

Tags: angular, ionic2

Following the v2 docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542395/switch-icon-in-ionic2-after-click) thread, I'm able to have the correct icon on click, although the default icon is not showing, the view returns undefined so no icon is rendered.
This is what I'm doing:

1. Loading data with a service from an API

   ```
    loadUserRepos(login: string): Observable<Repo[]> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.githubApiUrl}/users/${login}/repos`)
     .map(res => <Repo[]>(res.json()))
     }
   ```
2. Initializing the icon with default when I initialize the arrays of data:

   ```
   export class UserReposPage {
    public starIcon: string = 'star-outline';
    repos: Repo[];
    login: string;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private githubUsers: GithubUsers) {
      this.login = navParams.get('login');
      // this.login = login;
      githubUsers.loadUserRepos(this.login).subscribe(repos => {
      // this.starIcon = 'star-outline';
      this.repos = repos;
    })
   }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad UserReposPage');
      // this.starIcon = 'star-outline';
     }
     public changeIcon(item): void {
    // console.log(item);
      item.starIcon = 'star';
      }
    }
   ```
3. Added the binding in the template:

   ```
   <ion-card *ngFor="let repo of repos">
     // there is more layout markup
     <ion-icon [name]="repo.starIcon"></ion-icon>
   </ion-card>
   ```

So this is returning undefined, and even if I fill starIcon in the constructor, or in the viewLoaded event, I get undefined.
If I remove repo, the correct value(star-outline) renders the right icon, but I can't use the click anymore to switch.

4. Added the click event to the button wrapping the icon - and it works correctly

   ```
   public changeIcon(item): void {
   item.starIcon = 'star';
   }
   ```

What am I missing? It might be a silly question because I'm not saving the click anywhere, but still it bothers me not knowing ;) I hope I added enough info,
Thanks Everyone

Comment: Is `[name]="repo.starIcon"` inside an ngFor ?

Comment: can you add all the relevant code?